# What does in do or mean in an if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am JavaScript learner.  I like to skim code to learn new things.  Recently i was looking in jQuery and found a condition like : `if ( "zoom" in div.style )`. What is `in` and whats the condition being tested for here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It tests for the existence of a property in an object (including prototyped properties).

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6RVD2/1/

```
var obj = {someProp: 'someValue',
           anotherProp: 'anotherValue'  
           };

var empty_obj = {};

function F() {};

F.prototype.someProp = 'someValue';

var proto_obj = new F;

if( 'someProp' in obj ) { 
   alert('yep'); // alert fires
}


if( 'someProp' in empty_obj ) { 
   alert('yep');  // alert doesn't fire
}


if( 'someProp' in proto_obj ) { 
   alert('yep');  // alert fires
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/in).

It checks whether the object `div.style` as the *property* `zoom` (i.e. `div.style.zoom`).